# Match text only from first line and last line?

Tags: regex

How do I search text in the first line with regex and text in the last line with another regex
(multi-line string)

```
  (blablabla)
  blablabla
  blablabla
  (blablabla)
  blablabla
```

If there are two lines with text in parentheses, one regex to match only text from first line that contains parentheses and one regex to match only text from second line that contains parentheses.

Comment: Depending on your language, there should be a flag that controls whether `^` & `$` refer to lines or the whole string.

Comment: What language? What have you tried? What's your input format (file, array, multi-line string)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you made the question more clear, here you go:

`egrep "\(.*\)" <inputfile> | tail -1`

The `egrep` finds lines which contain text surrounded by parentheses. `tail -1` trims the output to the last line found.

Since I'm pretty sure you're not searching for things that look like (aabssa), http://rubular.com/ is an excellent regex reference/tester.

**Old answer below**

Since it's unclear you need to do these in the same step, or even compare them, how about this for the Unix shell.

**First Line:**`head -n 1 <input file> | egrep "<regex>"`

**Last Line:**`tail -n 1 <input file> | egrep "<regex>"`

Give us more info, and you'll probably get a more helpful answer.

Comment: Or more succinctly `sed -n -e '1/firstlineregex/p' -e '$/lastlineregex/p'`